# Amazon Rekognition from India

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I want to use Amazon Rekognition for some Detection project from India, each and every time I use to connect, either check for Region error pops up or S3 metadata issue?

botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the DetectLabels operation: Unable to get image metadata from S3.  Check object key, region and/or access permissions.

thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah, we have literally _nothing_ to go off here.

Comment: can't we use even by specifying 'us-east-1' or rest of the two ?

Answer (score 3):

[Amazon Rekognition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/what-is.html) is currently (March 2017) only available in these regions:

- US East (N. Virginia)
- US West (Oregon)
- EU (Ireland)

It is not (at the moment) available in the Mumbai region.

Comment: Then how come I am able to work with console.aws ?

Comment: When you use it in the console, take a look at the region in the top-right corner. It will be one of the above.